# Grails gsp template. Pass params from gsp and accept their on template

Tags: templates, grails, model, gsp, parameters

```
<g:each var="dep" in="${depList}">
 <tr>
  <td>
    ${dep.depName} 
  </td>
  <td>
    ${dep.location}
  </td>
  <td>
    <g:render template="listTemplate" model="${dep.clients}"/>
  </td>
  <td> 
    <g:checkBox name="departments" value="${dep.id}" checked="false" />
  </td>
 </tr>
</g:each>
```

From gsp page I need send model(params) depList on the template where I'm accept their/ How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

very close:

 `<g:render template="listTemplate" model="[clients:dep.clients]"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
<g:each var="dep" in="${depList}">
 <tr>
  <td>
    ${dep.depName} 
  </td>
  <td>
    ${dep.location}
  </td>
  <td>
    <g:render template="listTemplate" model="[clientlist: dep.clients]"/>
  </td>
  <td> 
    <g:checkBox name="departments" value="${dep.id}" checked="false" />
  </td>
 </tr>
</g:each>
```